# Load files using wildcard

Tags: matlab, input

I need to load a list of images, with names in the form `A_00001_01.jpeg`, `A_00001_02.jpeg`, `A_00021_01.jpeg`, `A_00030_01.jpeg`, `A_00039_01.jpeg`, `A_00039_02.jpeg`. I know the first index from a list; the second index is usually `01` but it can also be `02` or `03`. For a certain first index, I need to load all the files with that (the second index does not matter).

Is there a way to load the files with a wildcard, something like the pseudocode below (not working)?

```
load(sprintf('A_%05i_*.jpeg', First_idx))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load files / read images in a loop. You could just try loading files with sequential indices, but that's not going to work well if there are some indices missing etc. Assuming all your files are in the same directory, you can read the contents of that directory and then load only those files that match the pattern. If they are in multiple directories, you can also loop through those.

I used `strncmp` to check if the file name matches the pattern, assuming it's enough to simply ensure the first index matches. If e.g. you also need to make sure second index is a number, use `regexp` instead.

Finally, if you want to read images, you need to use `imread`, not `load`.

```
firstIdx = 1;
pattern = sprintf('A_%05i_', firstIdx);
flist = dir(); % specify actual directory path, if different from current folder
flist = flist(~[flist.isdir]); % leave only files
images = {};
for f = 1:length(flist)
    [~, name, ext] = fileparts(flist(f).name);
    if strcmp(ext, '.jpeg') && strncmp(pattern, name, length(pattern))
        images{end+1} = imread(flist(f).name);
    end
end
```